# Expression for the sum of another bounded series with arithmetic and geometric components

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

The expression I have is the following:

$S = \sum_{i=1}^T (1-q)^{i-1}i$

My expression after I play around with it is:

$S=  \frac{1-(1-q)^TT}{q}+\frac{1-q}{q} \left(\frac{1-(1-q)^{T-1}}{q}  \right) $

This looks a bit too complex to me so I think I might have made a mistake. 
Maybe some detail is warranted. $q \in [0,1]$ and $T \in N$

Comment: It is $$-\frac{q T (1-q)^T+(1-q)^T-1}{q^2}$$

Comment: Looks the same as mine! Oh good!